# What is reason for following sql code couldn't insert data?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-insert

My database have two column. One column is auto increment `id(Primary Key)` and other is `'Sentence'` column. Manually type something and I can insert that value. But when I'm trying insert variable value that gives error message. I tried different ways. `('?') /( ? )/(?)` Not work anything for me.

```
          int s1=9;
          String s2="Kasuni";
          String sql = "INSERT INTO sentences (Sentence) VALUES ( ? )";
          PreparedStatement pstmtJ = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          //pstmtJ.setInt(1, s1);
          pstmtJ.setString(1,s2);
          pstmtJ.executeUpdate(sql);
```

1st value I didn't insert because of that is auto increment value. I just comment and that shows in my above code.

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? )' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2642)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1647)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1566)
    at TestJsoup.main(TestJsoup.java:66)
```

When I'm tring following code:

```
          int s1=9;
          String s2="Kasuni";
          String sql = "INSERT INTO sentences (Sentence) VALUES ('?')";
          PreparedStatement pstmtJ = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          //pstmtJ.setInt(1, s1);
          pstmtJ.setString(1,s2);
          pstmtJ.executeUpdate(sql);
```

That gives following error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3646)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3630)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4481)
    at TestJsoup.main(TestJsoup.java:65)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pstmtJ.executeUpdate(sql);` → You're sending the original SQL string, since that is calling [Statement.executeUpdate(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29).

Use `pstmtJ.executeUpdate();` instead ([PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)) to execute the prepared statement.

Comment: :D Yes That's work for me. Thanx lot. I tried lot. Thanx again. Have a nice day :) .

Answer (score 1):

**Interface Statement**

```
int executeUpdate(String sql)
```

Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement. [refer java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

**public interface PreparedStatement extends Statement**

```
int executeUpdate()
```

Executes the SQL statement in this `PreparedStatement` object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.[refer java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

you are calling `executeUpdate(String sql)` which is from `Statement` interface, you have to call `executeUpdate()` from `PreparedStatement` interface to resolve issue.

Modified Code :

```
int s1=9;
String s2="Kasuni";
String sql = "INSERT INTO sentences (Sentence) VALUES ( ? )";
PreparedStatement pstmtJ = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//pstmtJ.setInt(1, s1);
pstmtJ.setString(1,s2);
pstmtJ.executeUpdate();
```