# JDBC Insert with Prepared Statement says I have SQL Syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, insert

I am trying a simple insert into my table but my program says I have a SQL Syntax error. Any ideas?

> SQL CODE

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
    start_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    end_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    seat VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    sep VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    price INT(50) NOT NULL,
    foroom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    printer INT(15) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (seat)
);
```

> JAVA CODE

```
try
{
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect...\n");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baseis?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","");
    System.out.println("Connection Succesful!!!");
    String sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (start_time)" + " VALUES (?)";
    PreparedStatement prepared = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepared.setString(1,"2016-07-17 19:00:00");
    prepared.executeUpdate(sql);
}
catch(SQLException error)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
}
```

> ERROR

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide values for all `NOT NULL` columns, and don't provide the `sql` string to `executeUpdate()`:

```
// set some values for the record
String seat = "";
String sep = "";
int price = 0;
String foroom = "";
int printer = 0;

String sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (start_time, end_time, seat, sep, price, foroom, printer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement prepared = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
prepared.setString(1, "2016-07-17 19:00:00");
prepared.setString(2, "2016-07-17 20:00:00");
prepared.setString(3, seat);
prepared.setString(4, sep);
prepared.setInt(5, price);
prepared.setString(6, foroom);
prepared.setInt(7, printer);
prepared.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Although that would be the second problem, it is not actually the problem that caused the error in the question. Your answer only fixes it 'accidentally' (because you used `prepared.executeUpdate()` instead of `prepared.executeUpdate(sql)`)

Comment: I was aware of that part of the fix, but didn't mention it explicitly. I've edited the answer to make it more obvious. Thanks!

Comment: just a note: with PostgreSQL, using `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, I had to use escaped double quotes around the table name: `"INSERT INTO \"order\" (customer) VALUES (?)"`, syntax error otherwise

Comment: That's because `order` is a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply values for all columns declared as 'NOT NULL'

The best way to debug problems like this is to capture the actual SQL statement sent to the database.

Comment: tried it, now I get this "Error: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)."

Comment: why does it say it has no parameters?

Comment: You don't need quotes around the string if you are using `PreparedStatement::setString()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085451/what-is-reason-for-following-sql-code-couldnt-insert-data

Comment: removed sql string fromexecuteUpdate(sql), still the same error